# If statement errors in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

I wrote a rather complex code but something doesn't seem correct. It returns error executing function.

Can you fix my code?

```
def reclass(siteclass,tempzone,rainzone):
        if 'ST' in siteclass and 'Sub-tropical' in tempzone and 'Wet' in rainzone:
            val = "Climatically-Suitable: Frost free, Optimal rainfall"
        elif 'ST' in siteclass and 'Sub-tropical' in tempzone and 'Moist' or 'Dry' in rainzone:
            val = "Sub-suitable: Frost free, average rainfall"
        elif 'WT' in siteclass and 'Warm temperate' in tempzone and 'Wet' or 'Moist' in rainzone:
            val = "Sub-suitable: Frost confined to hollows and low-lying areas, average rainfall"
        elif 'WT' in siteclass and 'Warm temperate' in tempzone and 'Dry' in rainzone:
            val = "Unsuitable: Frost confined to hollows and low-lying areas, below average rainfall"
        elif 'CT' in siteclass and 'Cool temperate' in tempzone and 'Wet' in rainzone:
            val = "Sub-suitable: Risk of frost, average rainfall"
        elif 'CT7' or 'CT8' or 'CT9' in siteclass and 'Cool temperate' in tempzone and 'Moist' in rainzone:
            val = "Sub-suitable: Risk of frost, average rainfall"
        elif 'CT1' or 'CT2' or 'CT3' or 'CT4' or 'CT5' or 'CT6' in siteclass and 'Cool temperate' in tempzone and 'Moist' in rainzone:
            val = "Unsuitable: Risk of frost, below average rainfall"
        elif 'CT' in siteclass and 'Cool temperate' in tempzone and 'Dry' in rainzone:
            val = "Unsuitable: Risk of frost, below average rainfall"
        return val
```

Expression:
Reclass(!SITE_CLASS!,!TEMP_ZONE!,!RAIN_ZONE!)

When I run the code now, it seems to work well for ST, however for WT and CT the wrong expression gets output.
[image]

Comment: Your function does not return anything.  return val would be in order here.  Also, include the full error in your post.  Consider using error handlers to pin down where the error is happening.

Comment: `"string_1" or "string_2" in some_variable` isn't the correct syntax, either.  That will always evaluate to true.  It should be `"string_1" in some_variable or "string_2" in some_variable`

Comment: Your last couple of questions are quite similar, and have been basic Python coding issues.  The `in` operator doesn't do what you seem to think it does, and Python logical operators don't work the way you're structuring them, either.  If you can't get the Python function to work in a `.py` file, then there's little point in passing it through to CalculateField as a string, which has much less error checking capability.

Comment: @GBG the code now works with return val, however, I seem to be getting the wrong output for CT and WT classes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As others point out, you can't use 'or' like that, since a string will almost always be True.

What you likely want is something like this:
Notice the initialysation of var, so it don't carry any old value, in case non of the criteria are fullfilled.

```
def reclass(siteclass, tempzone, rainzone):
   val = 'Undefined...'
   if 'ST' in siteclass: # and
       if 'Sub-tropical' in tempzone:
           if 'Wet' in rainzone:
               val = "Climatically-Suitable: Frost free, Optimal rainfall"
           elif 'Moist' or 'Dry' in rainzone:
               val = "Sub-suitable: Frost free, average rainfall"
   elif 'WT' in siteclass:
       if 'Warm temperate' in tempzone:
           if 'Wet' in rainzone or 'Moist' in rainzone:
               val = "Sub-suitable: Frost confined to hollows and low-lying areas, average rainfall"
           elif 'Dry' in rainzone:
               val = "Unsuitable: Frost confined to hollows and low-lying areas, below average rainfall"
   elif 'CT' in siteclass:
       if 'Cool temperate' in tempzone:
           if 'Wet' in rainzone:
               val = "Sub-suitable: Risk of frost, average rainfall"
           elif 'Dry' in rainzone:
               val = "Unsuitable: Risk of frost, below average rainfall"
   elif 'CT7' in siteclass or 'CT8' in siteclass or 'CT9' in siteclass:
       if 'Cool temperate' in tempzone:
           if 'Moist' in rainzone:
               val = "Sub-suitable: Risk of frost, average rainfall"
   elif 'CT1' in siteclass or 'CT2' in siteclass or 'CT3' in siteclass or 'CT4' in siteclass or 'CT5' in siteclass or 'CT6' in siteclass:
       if 'Cool temperate' in tempzone:
           if 'Moist' in rainzone:
               val = "Unsuitable: Risk of frost, below average rainfall"
   return val
```

or a little more Python'ic, using any() to replace multiple or. like this:

```
def reclass(siteclass, tempzone, rainzone):
    val = 'Undefined...'
    if 'ST' in siteclass: # and
        if 'Sub-tropical' in tempzone:
            if 'Wet' in rainzone:
                val = "Climatically-Suitable: Frost free, Optimal rainfall"
            elif 'Moist' or 'Dry' in rainzone:
                val = "Sub-suitable: Frost free, average rainfall"
    elif 'WT' in siteclass:
        if 'Warm temperate' in tempzone:
            if 'Wet' in rainzone or 'Moist' in rainzone:
                val = "Sub-suitable: Frost confined to hollows and low-lying areas, average rainfall"
            elif 'Dry' in rainzone:
                val = "Unsuitable: Frost confined to hollows and low-lying areas, below average rainfall"
    elif 'CT' in siteclass:
        if 'Cool temperate' in tempzone:
            if 'Wet' in rainzone:
                val = "Sub-suitable: Risk of frost, average rainfall"
            elif 'Dry' in rainzone:
                val = "Unsuitable: Risk of frost, below average rainfall"
    elif any([tok in siteclass for tok in ['CT1', 'CT2', 'CT3', 'CT4', 'CT5', 'CT6']]):
        if 'Cool temperate' in tempzone:
            if 'Moist' in rainzone:
                val = "Unsuitable: Risk of frost, below average rainfall"
    elif any([tok in siteclass for tok in ['CT7', 'CT8', 'CT9']]):
        if 'Cool temperate' in tempzone:
            if 'Moist' in rainzone:
                val = "Sub-suitable: Risk of frost, average rainfall"
    return val
```

Comment: The OP used `in` for equivalence -- your `any` array will never be reached, since `'CT' in siteclass` will get the flow of control before either of the two `elif` that follow. There are plenty of opportunities for incorrectly defined or undefined values.

Comment: Your right - CT takes all, my bad. But I still think the OP's long lines if 'and' and 'or' are messy to look at.

Comment: They are messy, but the solution is to use `in` properly, with `siteclass in ['CT1', 'CT2','CT3', 'CT4', 'CT5', 'CT6']` *before* the more generic test

Comment: You are right - as I wrote before. I'm sure OP can fix that easily, but I have now changed my answer to reflect it. Alternatively, all the val= can be changed to return, but you would still have to reorder the checks, and put general CT last. –